# Error source propagation in micro-service architecture

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, microservices

I am implementing a product that consists of *n* microservices (Java, Spring).

The problem is when some use case integrates ex. 4 microservices that communicates like that:

`A -> B -> C -> D`

and D throws an exception while doing its task. Service A needs to know that the source of the problem was service D.

I know that I can implement a custom exception handler in service D that can return some additional property like `exceptionSource="D"` and propagate this through all services, but it's not really cool and needs a lot of manual implementation.

Do you know any way to make it more automatic? Maybe there is some pattern/library/magic-spring-property for that?

Comment: This seems like a small extension to trace propagation. E.g. Zipkin or Jaeger

Comment: Zipkin is great when I need to monitor communication between services but afaik it will not extend the error response, so service A will not know that problem occurred in service D.

Answer (score 1):

Defining an exception handler and a error message forwarder in each microservice sounds indeed a bad idea.
It decouples the microservice implementations in a way that is not necessarily desirable.  We will decouple things that needs to be decoupled (such as data, logic, deployment) but transverse requirements between microservices should not be duplicated in each micro service implementation, overall if they rely on the same technologies.  That is clearly not maintainable.

I see two main ways to accomplish your task :

- relying on a third application that meshes/enriches the communication and that intercepts the response with the error message (via a specific pattern) and enrich the response of each caller will the source message error until the original invoker.
  This kind of solution makes sense if you already use it or if you use heterogeneous implementations concerning your microservices. You don't seem to be in this case.
- Defining an exception handler (`@ControllerAdvice`) and a HTTP interceptor (`ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`) in a shared library by all Java Spring microservices.
  In this way, all services will perform the exception handling and the processing of the error coming from responses from other microservices in a similarly way and without any effort.

Just a warn : microservices implementations are not designed to rely **only** on the same technology (one may be in Java Spring, the other one may be in Java EE, another in NodeJS and the next one in C#).
So relying on a specific feature of Spring may work now but could cause some difficulties if later you use another technology as Java and Spring.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinion. I like your first idea, but it looks a little like over-engineering in my case. The second approach with the shared library is something I tried in other case and unfortunately, it was not maintainable. But you right that I should avoid using spring-specific approach.

Comment: You are welcome. About the second approach, I think that for the moment it matches the best to your need as right now you are full spring (KISS) . Which problem of maintainability did you notice ?  This library should be completely generic and just handle the common part : that should mainly enrich the response returned with the suitable "exceptionSource" information. Maybe you should edit the post to explain your actual way of handling that point.  That is a very interesting matter, so  when I would have time to experiment something on my free time, I would edit my answer with a feedback.